# Applying classes to block level elements in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I cannot seem to apply styles using this style definition:

```
var object = {
    type: CKEDITOR.STYLE_BLOCK,
    attributes: {
        'class': 'foo'
    } 
};
```

`var style = new CKEDITOR.style(object);`

I have allowedContent set to true in my configs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Styles definitions in CKEditor don't have the `type` property. CKEditor uses `element` property to know when and how to apply the style:

```
var object = {
    element: 'h1', // This style will be applied to h1 element
    attributes: {
        'class': 'foo'
    } 
};
```

More examples on defining styles can be found in [official guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles).